# How to create a table which showing attributes from one layer and another?

Tags: qgis, layers, attribute-table, spatial-join, union

I have two layers.

The A12_zone system which is basically the zone system of UK

[image]

and then another layer with some developments.

Each layer has its own attribute table.

I would like to create a table where each development will have a corresponding number of zone depending on in which zone it falls.
So for instance the development zone mm falls in the 151 zone and that should be indicated in the final table!

[image]

Can you help me doing this in QGIS?

Comment: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_joins.html

Answer (score 4):

What you can perform is called "Spatial Join" or Join Attributes by Location. As mentioned, [this](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_joins.html) is a good source of how to perform the steps. I'll highlight some here.

You already have your data and have identified the fields you want to join.

Then you could begin the spatial join as shown here:

> Go to Vector ‣ Data Mangement Tools ‣ Join attributes by location.

[image]

> The Target vector layer is the one we want to add the attributes to.

[image]

> As we want to sum the capacity of your mm zones, select Take summary of intersecting features and choose Sum.

You will then have a column similar to "sum_capacity" which provides the total for your zones.

Answer (score 2):

There is a helpful plugin doing spatial joins quickly. It's called RefFunctions:

[image]

After installing the plugin you just have to add a new field to your point layer. Then enter the following expression:

```
geomwithin('targetLayer','targetField')
```

Please replace 'targetLayer' with name of the layer containing the A12 zone system polygons and 'targetField' with the name of the field containing the numbers.

[image]
[image]